# raytracer using pthreads

Tags: gcc, pthreads, raytracing

```
int main(int a, char *args[]) {
    int i;
    pthread_t threads[8];
    unsigned int* pixmap = malloc(1024*1024*sizeof(int));

    v_threadargs.height = 1024.0f;
    v_threadargs.width = 1024.0f;
    v_threadargs.pixmap = pixmap;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        v_threadargs.threadid = i;
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, render, (void *) &v_threadargs);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

    writetga(pixmap, 1024, 1024, "ray8out.tga");
    free(pixmap);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}

void *render(void *r_threadargs) {
    int i,j, threadid, start;
    float height, width;
    int *pixmap;

    struct s_threadargs *p_threadargs;
    p_threadargs = (struct s_threadargs *) r_threadargs;
    height = p_threadargs -> height;
    width = p_threadargs -> width;
    pixmap = p_threadargs -> pixmap;
    threadid = p_threadargs -> threadid;

    stepy = viewplaney0;
    deltax = (viewplanex1 - viewplanex0) / width;
    deltay = (viewplaney1 - viewplaney0) / height;
    stepy += deltay;

    float *viewer = (float[3]){0.0f, 0.0f, -7.0f};

    if (threadid == 1)
        start = 0;
    else
        start = threadid * height/8;

    for (i = start; i < (threadid + 1)*(height/8); i++) {
        stepx = viewplanex0;
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {
            float *color = (float[3]){0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
            float *raydir = (float[3]){stepx - viewer[0], stepy - viewer[1], 0 - viewer[2]};
            float maxdist = 100000.0f;
            normalize(raydir);
            trace(raydir, viewer, color,  0,maxdist);
            int r = (int)(roundf(color[0]*255.0f));
            if (r > 255) { r = 255; }
            int g = (int)(roundf(color[1]*255.0f));
            if (g > 255) { g = 255; }
            int b = (int)(roundf(color[2]*255.0f));
            if (b > 255) { b = 255; }
            pixmap[j+i*(int)width] = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | (b);
            stepx += deltax;
        }
        stepy += deltay;
    }
}
```

I am trying to implement this raytracer program using 8 threads (pthreads using gcc), but output image "ray8out.tga" is not correct. Program is executing correcly without any error but something missing in logic. It will be pleasure if someone please could help me, where is the error?

Answer (score 3):

You're passing the same threadargs structure to every thread; there's no guarentee that they'll start running before you change the threadid value. You should allocate a new threadargs structure with malloc for each thread (and free it from within the new thread itself).

Comment: Actually I am a new in threads. Do you mean that:

for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    v_threadargs[i].height = 1024.0f;
    v_threadargs[i].width = 1024.0f;
    v_threadargs[i].pixmap = pixmap;
    v_threadargs[i].threadid = i;
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, render, (void *) &v_threadargs[i]);
}

Comment: @Bilal, yes, using an array is an option as well as long as v_threadargs sticks around until all threads are joined.